# How do I send extra data with my form using jQuery Form Plugin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-plugins

In my .NET MVC4/razor app I have a form, and I want to include other data that is not found in the form as part of the request to my controller method.  However, it doesn't appear to be adding this extra data.  I'm running into a model binding error: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'B' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean'.. basically, it's not adding the extra data to the request.  Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Html:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "myForm", id = "myForm" }))
{
    //blah
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel viewModel, string A, bool B)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Javascript... I've tried this a couple of ways and cant get it to work.

beforeSerialize:

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm({
    beforeSerialize: function (form, options) {
        options.data = {
            A: "test",
            B: true
        };
    },
    success: function (result) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

beforeSubmit:

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function (formData, formObject, formOptions) {
        formData.push({A: "test", B: true });
    },
    success: function (result) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

data:

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm({
    data: {
        A: "test",
        B: true
    },
    success: function (result) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: oh also, I can't use a hidden input and change the value before serialization or submit, because while my example is simple, one of the data types is actually an object.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.  The problem is that the div containing my form was getting re-rendered on a different ajax event and blowing the binding magic that happens on page load.